# Cannot save request data to a file and pipe it to an external request at the same time

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node server (using express) that accepts an image as a blob.  I curently pipe this directly to an external request, i.e.:

```
app.post('/process', function(req, res) {
    req.pipe({url: '<url-to-external-server>',...}, 
        function(err,response,body) {
          //process external response.  
        }
    );      
}
```

This all works fine.  Now I would also like to save the data to disk as well, so I add that functionality, so the code now looks like:

```
app.post('/process', function(req, res) {
    var filename = generateUniqueFileName();
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    req.pipe(writeStream);

    req.pipe({url: '<url-to-external-server>',...}, 
        function(err,response,body) {
          //process external response.
          var respData = processBody(
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.send(respData);
          } else {
             // send error.
            res.send(...);
          }
        }
    );      
}
```

What happens is that the file is not saved correctly.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should leave that part to a library instead of doing it yourself.  [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is a good and easy library for that.

Comment: are you suggesting to change the way the route works make it take a form data with a file, and then read the file and stream that to the external request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One source stream can't be piped to 2 destination streams that way. You need to create a pass through stream (split source stream) to pipe to 2 different destinations.  Node's stream module has a pass through for that. Here is the revised code with the pass through:

```
app.post('/process', function(req, res) {
    // create a pass through stream
    var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;
    var passThroughStream = new PassThrough();

    var filename = generateUniqueFileName();
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

    req.pipe(passThroughStream);   // split it to this new stream
    passThroughStream.pipe(writeStream); // pipe this to 1st destination

    // now pipe it to 2nd destination 
    req.pipe({url: '<url-to-external-server>',...},
      function(err,response,body) {
        //process external response.
        var respData = processBody(
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.send(respData);
        } else {
            // send error.
            res.send(...);
        }
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!  Yesterday, I got as far as using a passthrough but I had the pipe to the external URL happen before the pipe to the passthrough and that resulted in an error.